# How to integrate these two?

Tags: calculus

For A>0,

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{t*E^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt$$

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{E^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt$$

My purpose is to derive
$$\lim_{A\rightarrow \infty}SinA\int^\infty_0 \frac{t*E^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt+CosA\int^\infty_0 \frac{E^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt=0$$

Comment: I have never seen this kind of thing before, but I tried this,

$$
\frac{1}{\cos(A)}(\sin(A)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt + \cos(A)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt) = \frac{0}{\cos(A)}
$$
leading me to
$$
\\tan(A) = \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt}
$$

Comment: Assuming you mean $e^{-At}$, and if you write $I_1(A)$ and $I_2(A)$ for the first and second integrals, respectively, then note that you have $I_2'(A)=-I_1(A)$ by differentiating under the integral sign. So you only need to figure out what $I_2$ is and you get the other for free. I would try contour integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use partial fraction decomposition and make the appropriate change of variables, you will find integrands looking like those appearing in exponential integrals $$I= \int \frac{e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt=\frac i2\Big(\int \frac{e^{-At}}{t-i}dt-\int \frac{e^{-At}}{t+i}dt\Big)$$ So, $$I=\frac i2\Big(e^{i A} \text{Ei}(-A (t+i))-e^{-i A} \text{Ei}(-A (t-i))\Big)$$ and $$J= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt=\text{Ci}(A) \sin (A)+\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(A)) \cos (A)$$ where appear the sine and cosine integrals.

Fo the second integral, it is simple : do the same but write $$I= \int \frac{te^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt=\frac i2\Big(\int \frac{(t-i+i)e^{-At}}{t-i}dt-\int \frac{(t+i-i)e^{-At}}{t+i}dt\Big)$$ and simplify.

Similarly, you could establish that $$K= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{te^{-At}}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(A)) \sin (A)-\text{Ci}(A) \cos (A)$$ So $$K \sin(A)+J \cos(A)=\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(A))$$ which tends to $0$ if $A$ goes to $\infty$.

All of the above asssume $A>0$.

Comment: You know,I'm not sure if I could do a computation like this if I was forced to-which really aggravates me.But your "plug and chug" skills get rusty after years of just proving theorems. Which is why you need to keep reviewing it periodically-like I should. Like we all should.But here's MY question-can the answer be derived without complex numbers? I'm not sure.